# Zipping files greater than 2GB in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I ve been trying to zip all the files in partcular directory into a single zip file and then transfer it to destination server. command i ve used is like

```
zip -j $Zipfilename *
```

the problem is sometimes the total size of all the files is reaching > 2GB so i'm getting below warning

```
zip warning: name not matched
```

and files are not getting zipped .Is there is anyother way to do it, without getting the above error? Please help me out!!

Comment: couldn't you just stay under the 2GB limit, by creating multiple zip files?

Comment: The warning message does not appear to be related to file size limits at all. Have you tried `zip -j $Zipfilename directory/` instead of wildcards?

Comment: @grawity Interestingly, I've read that `zip` can't produce files bigger than 2GB.

Comment: @slhck: The limit of the usual ZIP *file format* is [either 2 GB or 4 GB](http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#limits) depending on the program, although Zip64 [has been published by PKWare](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). I'm not sure about the limitations of the `zip` utility (which I think is InfoZIP).

Comment: What OS? The Posix [`pax`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pax) utility can emulate tar/cpio and: "The cpio and ustar formats can only  support  files  up  to  8589934592
       bytes (8 * 2^30) in size."

Answer (score 11):

Zip is not known to be able to create ZIPs greater than 2GB in size. For better or worse, Linux has other tools such as `tar`, `gzip`, `bzip` and others that you can use which have a much higher limit on what they can create. However, if you insist on sticking to ZIP, you could try and use the `--split-size` directive like so:

`zip -j --split-size 2g $zipfilename *`

In case you're wondering about the alternatives...

**Creating with Tar**

> `tar -cf name_of_zip.tar directory/`

This will create a simple Tar(ball) file. Good for on-the-fly and when you need to get something out quick.

> `tar -czf name_of_zip.tar.gz directory/`

This creates a Tar-Gzipped file of a directory. `tar-gz` is a Tar(ball) that has been further compressed by `gzip`. It's slightly slower than a standard Tar operation, but provides pretty good compression for what you're getting.

> `tar -cjf name_of_zip.tar.bz directory/`

This creates a Tar-BZipped file of a directory. `tar-bz` is the slowest tar option you can use, but provides the greatest amount of compression on top of the tar.

Untarring is a simple matter of replacing the `-c` switch with a `-x` switch. IE:

> tar -xzf /tmp/some_file.tar.gz

Which untars the `/tmp/some_file.tar.gz` tar(ball) into whatever directory I'm currently in.

**Creating with gzip**

> gzip -c file file2 file3 > newfile.gz`

Creates a new gzip file from a file, or a bunch of files.

> gzip -cr directory/ > newfile.gz`

Creates a new gzip from a directory.

Unzipping is a matter of simply using `gunzip` on your `gzip` file.

**Creating with bzip**

BZip doesn't do directory traversal, so it's only good for zipping up one-or-many files.

> `bzip2 -ck file -<number> > compress.bz`

where  is a number between 1 and 9, 1 being the lowest level of compression and 9 being the highest.

Answer (score 2):

unzip version 6.0 and zip version 3.0 support greater than 2GB files.

New features in UnZip 6.0, released 20 April 2009:

- Support PKWARE ZIP64 extensions, allowing Zip archives and Zip
  archive entries larger than 4 GiBytes and more than 65536 entries
  within a single Zip archive. This support is currently only available
  for Unix, OpenVMS and Win32/Win64.
- Support for bzip2 compression method.

New features in Zip 3.0, released 7 July 2008:

- large-file support (i.e., > 2GB)
- support for more than 65536 files per archive
- multi-part archive support
- bzip2 compression support

Answer (score 1):

unix-way is to use `tar` for multiplexing files together and `gzip`/`bzip2`/any-other-compressor to compress `.tar` archive.