# Creating a ZIP file that extracts cross platform

Tags: linux, windows, macos, compression

I need to distribute a large (6GB+) file cross-platform. For practical reasons, I want to zip it down to 2GB+. I originally used Mac OS 10.11 to create the zip file using the Archive Utility. It extracted fine on my Linux but wouldn't extract on Windows 10 (using the system utility). When compressing the original file on Linux, I can extract it on Windows 10 but it fails to extract on Mac OS X. When I try to extract it using the command line program `unzip` on Mac OS X, I get the following error:

```
Archive:  UbuntuLTS.vdi.zip
warning [UbuntuLTS.vdi.zip]:  76 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [UbuntuLTS.vdi.zip]:  reported length of central directory is
  -76 bytes too long (Atari STZip zipfile?  J.H.Holm ZIPSPLIT 1.1
  zipfile?).  Compensating...
   skipping: UbuntuLTS.vdi           need PK compat. v4.5 (can do v2.1)

note:  didn't find end-of-central-dir signature at end of central dir.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

The Mac is running `zip` 3.0 (July 5th, 2008) and `unzip` 5.52 (28 February, 2005). The Linux is running `zip` 3.0 (July 5th, 2008) and `unzip` 6.00 (20 April, 2009). No idea what Windows is using. I need the zip to properly extract on Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows (7, 8, 8.1, and 10). I would like to avoid telling people to download a third-party program. I would also like to understand what the heck is going on. I never had trouble with the zip format being incompatible on different platforms.

For any solution you propose, out-of-the-box post-Windows Vista is a must as those will be the biggest target group. I'm aware that asking for it to work on "Linux" is a little ill-defined.

Comment: You are not creating a self-extracting zip archive but just an ordinary zip archive? Do you use 64bit versions of zip? Maybe http://superuser.com/q/394905/504096 answers your question this text (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#ZIP64) helps you? Originally, the zip standard allowed only 4 GB to be compressed (not the size of the resulting archive file).

Comment: I was not aware of the size limitation. It seems then, the culprit is Mac OS X not supporting ZIP64 unzipping. From the Wikipedia reference you provided, I'd infer that all post-XP Windows releases have ZIP64 support. For OS X users I might have to provide an alternative .tar.gz download. Great job, Apple.

Comment: Apparently, version 6.0 of unzip for Mac support larger files (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220054, http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35967/unzip). Here are some further hints on how to obtain the version 6.0: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/149080 . Is this worth an answer to your question?

Comment: If you want to go through the trouble of reposting this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Unfortunately, I cannot assume my audience is able to install something via homebrew, so I will stick to a separate tar.gz.

Comment: There is a Mac version of the Windows program 7zip available. Maybe it is possible for your audience to install it. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unzip` version prior to version 6.0 do not support extracting zip files which are larger than 4 Gb as uncompressed files (or 2 Gb, http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#limits). See for example https://superuser.com/a/394915/504096 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220054 .

Unfortunately, the standard version of `unzip` provided by MacOS is not 6.0 but 5.X. Version 6.0 for MacOS can be obtained here: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35967/unzip . This article describes how to install version 6: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/149080

Additionally, `unzip` needs to be compiled with the options `LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT` and `ZIP64_SUPPORT` in order to be able to process files above 2 Gb / 4 Gb. Commonly, this should be the case. To find out, whether `unzip` was compiled accordingly, type `unzip -version`. There should be something like this in the output:

```
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009 ...
...
UnZip special compilation options:
...
LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT (large files over 2 GiB supported)
ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
....
```

An alternative to `unzip` was to use `7zip` which is unofficially available for non-Windows operating systems - like MacOS (named `7zX`).